# How to launch a scheduled task as AzureAD user?

Tags: tasks

I am working on an AzureAD-joined Win11 computer with logged on AzureAD-user. I need to create a scheduled task to run an executable as this user, but this is not possible. E.g. when I try to run c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe it throws an error "Application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect". Of course I can run notepad locally and I am also a local admin on that machine. What's wrong here?